# Java with Pagination

Tags: java, pagination, records

I am working on writing a java client code which calls a web service. When I make a call to one of my client's web service, its accepting the input parameter like below:

```
KalturaFilterPager pager = new KalturaFilterPager();
    pager.pageIndex = 1;
    pager.pageSize = 50;
```

So If i have 430 records, I need to change the input parameter everytime like pageIndex =2 pageSize =50 like this to get all the records.

Now my requirement is I want to retrieve all my records in one page. How can I do this without specifying pageSize =431 as this record number might change in the future.

My code is:

```
private static String getMediaMetadata() throws KalturaApiException,
        IOException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
    getKalturaClient();
    String country = null;
    KalturaMediaService mediaService = client.getMediaService();
    System.out.println("Got the mediaservice" + mediaService);
    KalturaMediaEntryFilter filter = new KalturaMediaEntryFilter();
    KalturaFilterPager pager = new KalturaFilterPager();
    pager.pageIndex = 1;
    pager.pageSize = 50;
    KalturaMediaListResponse mediaResponse = mediaService.list(filter,
            pager);
    if (mediaResponse.totalCount > 0) {
        System.out.println("mediaResponse.totalCount"
                + mediaResponse.totalCount);
        // pager.pageSize = mediaResponse.objects;
        List<KalturaMediaEntry> mediaEntriesList = mediaResponse.objects;
        if (mediaEntriesList != null && mediaEntriesList.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mediaEntriesList.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("mediaEntriesList.size()-------->"
                        + mediaEntriesList.size());
                KalturaMediaEntry media = mediaEntriesList.get(i);
                if (media != null) {
                    System.out.println("Media ID -------->" + media.id);
                    KalturaMetadataListResponse metadataResp = getMetadata(media.id);
                    if (metadataResp != null && metadataResp.totalCount > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Got the metadataResp"
                                + metadataResp.totalCount);
                        List<KalturaMetadata> metadataObjs = metadataResp.objects;
                        if (metadataObjs != null && metadataObjs.size() > 0) {
                            System.out.println("got the metadaobjs");
                            for (int j = 0; j < metadataObjs.size(); j++) {
                                KalturaMetadata metadata = metadataObjs
                                        .get(j);
                                if (metadata != null) {
                                    System.out
                                            .println("metadata not null --------->"
                                                    + metadata);
                                    String xml = metadata.xml;
                                    if (xml != null) {
                                        System.out
                                                .println("xml not null --------->"
                                                        + xml);
                                        country = parseXml(xml);
                                        if (country != null) {
                                            System.out
                                                    .println("Country Value --------->"
                                                            + country);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return country;
}
```

Comment: read documentation of that web service

Answer (score 0):

is there any way to get total number of records before actually getting records? Is there such an API ? If so, call that first use that value as the page size instead.

Comment: I have the same method which doesn't take any parameters and returns the total count. I called this method and then taking that value and setting to the pager object and call the method again: pager.pageSize = mediaResponse.objects.size();
   pager.pageIndex = 1;
   KalturaMediaListResponse resp = mediaService.list(filter, pager); But still in the for loop its showing 30 records only which is default page records size.

Comment: Some API's define a max size for pageSize. Try to find out what's the max for your case. Why don't you try pagesizes like 75, 100, 125, 150, 200 etc to find out if it would make any diff?

Comment: Thank u for ur response. This doesn't have any max size to set and retrieve. I have tried like setting 50 as pageSize and 1,2,3,4,5 etc as pageIndex. This is working fine. But I want to iterate all the objects in a loop and do some other processing. This is where Its failing.